# Registering many services in 1 kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I have converted my docker-compose file into kubernetes through kompose. There are many services,deployments, persistentvolumeclaim files. I can run independent service at one time, but i want to register all the services in one UI.

Till now i have did these folllowing steps:

-create persistentvolume.yaml file

-kubectl create -f consul-claim0-persistentvolume.yaml

- kubectl create -f consul-claim1-persistentvolume.yaml

  -kubectl create -f consul-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml

  -kubectl create -f consul-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yamlkube

  -kubectl create -f consul-deployment.yaml

  -kubectl expose deployment consul --name=consul-svc --target-port=8500 --type=NodePort

  -this ran my consul on http://host:31827/ui/#/dc1/services/consul

Then I am trying to run other services now on http://host:31827/ui/#/dc1/services/ .

Please suggest some steps.

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are asking. What UI do you mean? kubernetes-dashboard?

Comment: The UI I am talking is related to my project. This project is having many services and all the services are manged in one dashboard. So I want all the services to run and manage all these services through kubernetes.